# Can not get WebRTC track event triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, webrtc

I am beginner at WebRTC and tried to make peer connection between two browser windows. I implemented simple websocket server in nodejs running locally. Everything seems fine until making candidates. The remote stream does not starting after exchanging candidates. I searched and run several examples but could not get mine work.

My UI has some inputs for communication. Here is what I am doing for calling:

1. Enter username as `user1` in first window and enter remote username as `user2` in first window
2. Enter username as `user2` in second window and enter remote username as `user1` in second window
3. Click to `Connect to server` button in each two windows. (Signaling server will know them after this).
4. Select my first camera device in first window and select my second camera device in second window. (Cameras will start after that)
5. Click call in first window

The problem is: Remote stream displays on the callee window (second window) but from dev console of caller window (first window) I don't see the `onTrack` function run. So remote stream does not display on caller. But I see the candidate logs.

So the caller does not see the callee, but callee sees the caller.

`index.html` I open this file twice in two browser windows (as file://...).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Webrtc Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>Signaling Server addres:</span>
          <input type="text" id="serverAddress" value="localhost:3001" onload="window.serverAddress = this;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>Username:</span>
          <input type="text" id="username" value="user1" onload="window.username = this;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>Target username:</span>
          <input type="text" id="remoteUsername" value="user2" onload="window.remoteUsername = this;" />
        </td>
        <td>Devices</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea
            name="log"
            id="log"
            cols="50"
            rows="10"
            style="width: 100%; resize: vertical;"
          ></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <video
            id="selfVideo"
            autoplay
            playsinline
            muted
            onload="window.selfVideo = this;"
          ></video>
        </td>
        <td>
          <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline onload="window.remoteVideo = this;"></video deo>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
          <div>
            <div>Video:<input id="videoCheck" type="checkbox" onload="window.videoCheck = this;" checked /></div>
            <select
              id="videoDevices"
              size="5"
              onload="window.videoDevices = this;"
              onchange="startSelf();"
            ></select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>Audio:<input id="audioCheck" type="checkbox" onload="window.audioCheck = this;" /></div>
            <select
              id="audioDevices"
              size="5"
              onload="window.audioDevices = this;"
              onchange="startSelf();"
            ></select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div
            style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;"
          >
            <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect to server</button>
            <button id="call" onclick="call();">Call</button>
            <button id="hangup" onclick="hangup();">Hang up</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script> -->
    <script src="adapter.js"></script>
    <script src="setup.js"></script>
    <script src="socket.js"></script>
    <script src="rtc.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`setup.js` for detecting input devices and creating options at page load.

```
const detectDevices = (deviceInfos) => {
  for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    const deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    const element = document.createElement("option");
    element.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === "videoinput") {
      element.innerText =
        deviceInfo.label || `camera ${videoDevices.length + 1}`;
      videoDevices.add(element);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === "audioinput") {
      element.innerText =
        deviceInfo.label || `microphone ${audioDevices.length + 1}`;
      audioDevices.add(element);
    }
  }
};

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
  .then((stream) => {
    window.localStream = stream;
    return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  })
  .then(detectDevices)
  .then(() => {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
    delete localStream;
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log("Error detecting devices", error));

const startSelf = async () => {
  if (videoCheck.checked && !videoDevices.value) {
    videoDevices.selectedIndex = 0;
  }

  if (audioCheck.checked && !audioDevices.value) {
    audioDevices.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
  const vDevId = videoDevices.value;
  const aDevId = audioDevices.value;
  // const constraints = {
  //   audio: { deviceId: aDevId ? { exact: aDevId } : undefined },
  //   video: { deviceId: vDevId ? { exact: vDevId } : undefined }
  // };
  const constraints = {};
  if (videoCheck.checked) {
    constraints.video = { deviceId: vDevId ? { exact: vDevId } : undefined };
  }
  if (audioCheck.checked) {
    constraints.audio = { deviceId: aDevId ? { exact: aDevId } : undefined };
  }
  await navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      window.localStream = stream;
      selfVideo.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error start self", error));
};
```

`socket.js`

```
let ws;

const send = (obj) => {
  const message = {
    from: username.value,
    to: remoteUsername.value
  };

  message.data = btoa(JSON.stringify(obj));
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
};

const connect = () => {
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + serverAddress.value);
  registerEvents();
};

const registerEvents = () => {
  ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log("websocket open");
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ from: username.value, data: "merheba" }));
  };

  ws.onmessage = (m) => {
    // parse message
    const message = JSON.parse(m.data);
    if (message.data === "siye de merheba") {
      console.log("connected to server");
      return;
    }
    const data = JSON.parse(atob(message.data));
    message.data = data;
    console.log("message: ", message);
    switch (data.type) {
      case "offer":
        onReceiveOffer(data);
        break;
      case "answer":
        onReceiveAnswer(data);
        break;
      case "candidate":
        console.log("received ice candidate", data);
        pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
        break;
    }
  };
};
```

`rtc.js` for webrtc calling functions

```
let pc;

const initSelf = async () => {
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
  pc.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
  pc.ontrack = onTrack;
  await startSelf();
  pc.addStream(localStream);
};

const call = async () => {
  if (!window.localStream || !pc) {
    await initSelf();
  }
  // send offer
  pc.createOffer().then((offer) => {
    pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    console.log("sending offer");
    send(offer);
  });
};

const onReceiveOffer = async (receivedOffer) => {
  console.log("offer receive", receivedOffer);
  if (!window.localStream || !pc) {
    initSelf();
  }
  pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(receivedOffer));
  log.value = JSON.stringify(receivedOffer);
  // answer
  await pc.createAnswer().then((answer) => {
    pc.setLocalDescription(answer);
    console.log("answer created: ", answer);
    send(answer);
  });
};

const onReceiveAnswer = async (receivedAnswer) => {
  console.log("answer receive", receivedAnswer);
  pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(receivedAnswer));
  log.value = JSON.stringify(receivedAnswer);
};

const onTrack = async (event) => {
  console.log("Add track");
  remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
};

const onIceCandidate = async (event) => {
  if (event.candidate) {
    console.log("ICE candidate");
    send({
      type: "candidate",
      candidate: event.candidate
    });
  }
};

const hangup = () => {
  if (pc) {
    pc.close();
    pc = null;
  }
  localStream.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
  delete localStream;
};
```

Signaling server `wsServer.js` running with `node wsServer.js`

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const wsserver = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3001 }, () => {
  console.log("server started");
});

let clients = [];

wsserver.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log("Message: %s", message);

    let data;
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Invalid JSON");
      data = {};
      return;
    }

    if (!data.from || data.from === "") {
      console.log("unknown sender");
      return;
    }

    if (!clients[data.from]) {
      console.log("client add: ", data.from);
      clients[data.from] = socket;
    }

    if (data.data === "merheba") {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({ data: "siye de merheba" }));
      clients[data.from] = socket;
      return;
    }

    if (data.to) {
      const target = clients[data.to];
      if (target) {
        console.log("forwarding to " + data.to);
        // console.log(target);
        target.send(message);
      }
    }
  });

  // socket.on("close", () => {
  //   if (socket.username) {
  //     delete clients[socket.from];
  //   }
  // });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax:

```
RTCPeerConnection.ontrack = eventHandler;
```

So looking at your code it should be something like:

```
self.ontrack = onTrack;
```

The way you did it for onicecandidate

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did some changes including this. But problem is partially solved. Now the remote video displays on second window, but still doesn't display on first window who made the call. I updated the question. Maybe something is going wrong while receiving answer?

Comment: @user12043 You need to include that part in the localVideo seperately.
The perfect flow is..1) establish peer connection 2) on answer request video (only once)
the first request video from caller to callee initiates negotiation and that once done will send back an answer again..
on that answer callee can request the video from the second side...
https://github.com/smitkpatel16/rsvp_vidcall/blob/master/sources/js/chatroom.js
refer to this file.. this is designed for mutli-party

Answer (score 0):

I putted some `window.localStream` and moved the contents of `initSelf()` inside `startSelf()`. I do not know why but problem resolved.

```
const startSelf = async () => {
  // creating pc object first
  if (!pc) {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
    pc.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
    pc.ontrack = onTrack;
  }

  // some code ...

  await navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      window.localStream = stream;
      pc.addStream(window.localStream); // adding the stream before showing
      selfVideo.srcObject = window.localStream;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error start self", error));
};
```

final content here: https://github.com/user12043/webrtc-try